# PostgreSQL: Select latest entries only when values differ in a column

Tags: sql, postgresql, date

Imagine the data:

```
id   audit_id   val     updated_at
1    11         43      October 09, 2021, 07:55 AM
1    12         34      October 11, 2021, 11:03 PM
1    13         88      January 23, 2022, 01:03 AM
1    14         34      January 23, 2022, 09:41 AM
2    21         200     June 28, 2021, 08:07 PM
2    22         200     December 23, 2021, 03:20 PM
2    23         205     January 12, 2022, 10:15 AM
2    24         211     May 13, 2022, 04:02 AM
```

Per id, I would like to return the two latest entries of different dates (not just timestamp, the date part should be different):

```
id   audit_id   val     updated_at
1    12         34      October 11, 2021, 11:03 PM
1    14         34      January 23, 2022, 09:41 AM
2    23         205     January 12, 2022, 10:15 AM
2    24         211     May 13, 2022, 04:02 AM
```

I assume I need to use partition and lag on the audit_id but I don't know how to start structuring it.

Comment: Is `audit_id = 13` supposed to be in 2021 or 2022?

Comment: yes! I made a typo. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would attack this in two parts.  The first would make sure only the latest from a single date is kept.  The second numbers the rows starting with the latest.

```
with by_day as (
  select *, 
         updated_at::date != 
           lag(updated_at::date) over (partition by id 
                                           order by updated_at desc) keep
    from imagined_data
), numbered as (
  select *, row_number() over (partition by id
                                   order by updated_at desc) as rn
    from by_day
   where coalesce(keep, true)
)
select id, audit_id, val, updated_at
  from numbered
 where rn <= 2;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=7689f52183e097e62956b85a2589cfb4)*

Answer (score 1):

Number rows in each group of same id such that the last two timestamps get number 1 and 2, then select only them.

```sql
select x.id, x.audit_id, x.val, x.updated_at
from (
  select t.id, t.audit_id, t.val, t.updated_at
       , row_number() over (partition by t.id order by t.updated_at desc) as rn
  from your_table t
) x
where x.rn <= 2
order by x.id asc, x.updated_at asc
```

Caution: I composed it in my head, didn't try it. Also if your `updated_at` column is actual text, it needs to be converted - I assume it is of timestamp type and the verbose format in your question is just (not very practical) presentation.

Comment: Hi! Noted I didn't clarified something. The dates must be different and not just the timestamp. How could I adjust it for that?

Comment: Yes, then the two steps are unavoidable as in Mike's solution.